# How to increase lvm on a extended partition?

Tags: lvm

I am trying to increase the LVM.

I have extended `nvme0n1p2` to 29G using `growpart`, but I am not sure what I should do next ... please advise. Thanks!

```
nvme0n1         259:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0   29G  0 part 
      ├─centos-root 253:0    0    6G  0 lvm  /
      └─centos-swap 253:1    0  800M  0 lvm  [SWA
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. I can infer from your question that you are running CentOS, but could you provide some more information on the exact OS version and the file systems used?

Comment: You're probably looking for `resize2fs`

Comment: The following commands (with the appropriate arguments) need to be run in order: pvck, pvresize, (pvck again?), lvresize and only then can e2fsck and resize2fs be called on centos/root, assuming that you want to increase the size of your root file-system as it is not exactly clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Next steps to max increase lv size would be: 1) `pvresize /dev/nvme0n1p2` 2) `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root` 3) and depending on file system you use there `resize2fs -f /dev/centos/root` (ext2/ext3/ext4 file system resizer) or `xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root` (expand an XFS filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

After growing the partition, you need to resize the physical volume which makes it available to LVM:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Once that’s done, you can resize your logical volumes; the simplest approach for that on the command line is to use `lvresize` with its `fsadm` integration:

```
sudo lvresize -r -L10G centos/root
```

for example, to resize the root volume to 10G.

Comment: thanks! it worked! i also used @Yurko's trick to use 100% free space.

Comment: thanks! it worked! i also used @Yurko's trick to use 100% free space.
do i need to run resize2fs or xfs_growfs ? because i can see the size grows in lsblk.
nvme0n1         259:0    0   30G  0 disk 

├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0    1G  0 part /boot

└─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0   29G  0 part 

  ├─centos-root 253:0    0 28.2G  0 lvm  /

  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  800M  0 lvm  [SWAP]

Comment: If you used the `-r` flag with `lvresize`, that took care of resizing the file system for you, so you don’t need to run `resize2fs` or `xfs_growfs`.

Comment: thank you Stephen! nice trick!..I didn't use `-r` with `xfs_lvresize`, it seems like i need to use `xfs_growfs`. ..

Comment: I did a `lsblk -f` hoping to find the file system. It looks like `centos-root` is using xfs, therefore, I executed `xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root` as suggested by Yurko. Looks like it all worked out! thank you all for the inputs!